# is "would be watched" the correct tense in this context?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

This is my sentence:

> Users' ratings keep changing. For instance, if a user watches a movie today, he might give it 5 stars, while if he wanted to rate it after 1 year, he might not give it 5 starts because he **would be watched** more movies or not interested in it as he was the first time he watched it.

I feel that I make mistake when I wrote **would be watched**, but I'm not sure.

Tried to search bud couldn't' find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but not quite right!  The correct wording is "he would **have** watched more movies".  The rule of thumb is that we use *be* for things that you *are*, and *have* for things that you *do*.  For example,

> He would **have** eaten all the food
>   He would **have** learned more
>   He would **have** grown taller

but

> He would **be** taller
>   He would **be** hungry
>   He would **be** looking out the window

Comment: In this case, "he would have watched" is correct and "he would watch" doesn't really make sense because we're talking about things that have happened between today and one year from now.   This is assuming I understand the OP's question properly, of course!

Comment: @stangdon thank you, please could you help me in my new quesiotn if you got time ?